# Jquery hiding the iframe correctly, but not showing it on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Using the jquery below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#myiframe").hide(); });
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#submit").click(function(){ $("#myiframe").delay(1000).show(0); }); });
</script>
```

I can successfully hide my iframe that is stated in an "if" even in a php script.
See below:

```
<?php
   $minAge = 22;
   $minAge *= 3600*24*365.25;  // $minAge in seconds

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $birth_date = strtotime($_POST['dob']);
      $now = strtotime("now");
      $age = $now - $birth_date; // age is in seconds
?>
    <iframe id = "myiframe" style='position: absolute; z-index: 10; height: 100%;'
            src = "<?php echo ($age > $minAge ? 'http://URL1.com' : 'http://URL2.com'); ?>"
            frameborder = "0"
            width = "350px"
    </iframe>
```

But upon clicking a button that should show the iframe, I want it shown with a one second delay (as shown in the jquery).

See the button implemented in a form here:

```
    <form method="post" id="form">
        <p2>Please select your date of birth below to verify your age.</p2>
        <input type="date" name="dob">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Age" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

The full code is here:
http://pastebin.com/EaafieB7

Basically what it should do is: hide iframe by default, show it with a delay when it's needed.
And so far it's only hiding successfully.

If anyone can point out where I am going wrong, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Is the page reloading itself when you're hitting submit? Because I don't see you preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: Try: `$(document).ready(function(){$("#submit").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$("#myiframe").delay(1000).show(0); }); });`

Comment: @denat huh? no the page is not reloading itself, I don't want it to do that. without hiding the iframe with the jquery script in the header, it shows up fine (the iframe), however I want it to show with a delay, so I hide it by default and want to show it again with a delay, using `.show()`

Comment: @Snowlav Try a `setTimeout`

Comment: @vihan1086 , thanks for the suggestion but it's not loading or showing the iframe when implementing that code. (code from your first reply)

Comment: When you click a button with `type="submit"` the default action is to post the form. If you don't want to post anything, then you should either use `type="button"` or use `e.preventDefault()` as has been suggested. Also, have you tested this without the `delay()`? If so, did it show immediately?

Comment: @Snowlav maybe `.show()` is acting up, try `.css('display', 'block');`

Comment: @jwatts1980 I do want it to post, but I want the iframe to showup with a delay

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see what you're trying to do now, but it's not gonna work that way. There are two ways you can go about this:

1. Do the age verification check in PHP and print the iframe only if the verification is successful. The downside of this is that it will reload the page, a behavior which you apparently don't want.
2. Do the age verification check in Javascript, but you will have to intercept your form submit handler to have it not reload the page, via `e.preventDefault()`.

A third alternative would be to use an AJAX call if you really insist in using PHP for age verification, but that would just be overdoing it.

Comment: hello and thanks for your input, I'd like to know why you think this is not going to work. since I am able to hide the iframe with jqeury, and still have it load, why can I not simply show it again?

Comment: Because you do the age verification check via PHP, and that code can't be reached unless the form is submitted (and the page reloaded). The best you can do is have the form submitted (and page reloaded) and then have the iframe show itself after a delay.

Comment: That's not true, the php works fine without refreshing the page.

Comment: There is no way the PHP code is running without the page being refreshed on submit. It might be happening too fast for you to notice it, but it's happening.

Comment: the page is loading the contents (iframe) after I submit the form, however the content displayed on the page is not being refreshed, grab my full code from the pastebin, delete the jquery and you can check for yourself :)

Comment: @Snowlav If you are not actively preventing the `submit` button from reloading the page, then the page is reloading. That is the purpose of the `submit` button. Since you did not include an `action` attribute on your `form` tag it will submit to the current page.

Comment: Also, `$age > $minAge` should probably be `$age >= $minAge`.

Comment: I am not having any problems with my php, can we focus on the jQuery issue please? It's still not parsing `.show()` correctly, it stays hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery can be rewritten as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myiframe').hide();
      $('#form').submit(function() {
          setTimeout(function() { $('#myiframe').show();}, 1000);
      });
});
```

Since you're submitting a form, it is appropriate to use the `submit` event handler instead of `click`. I'm not very familiar with jQuery's `delay` function, but `setTimeout` sets a delay for the specified time and should achieve what you're looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: The iframe is hiding correctly, I also notice the iframe is loading, however it's not showing after a delay. It stays hidden.

Comment: What URL's are you using as iframe src? First of all, the page is reloading on submit, as **denat** said - you can tell by submitting your age and trying to refresh the page - you're given a warning about resending post data. As for the iframe not loading the content, check your console (inspect element in Safari or Google Chrome) and you'll see that sites like Google, Yahoo, Facebook, etc. block iframe access like you're trying.

Comment: URL1.com and URL2.com, both show fine in iframe. everything works completely fine without jquery, however I want to add a delay in between the submit button and the visitor seeing the iframe in jQuery, for some reason I have NO troubles hiding the iframe with the code in the OP but I cannot show it again after hiding.

Comment: Right, and the issue is because the browser is submitting data and reloading the page before you can give it the delay to show. As **denat** mentioned, you'd need to use e.preventDefault() in the  `.submit(function(e) {...})` call, as this will prevent a regular server call without AJAX. Load your page without submitting an age and view the source code, you'll see that the iframe isn't even there **until** you submit a date. Does any of that make sense?

Comment: it makes sense, kind off, what I end up doing is: `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#myiframe").hide(); });</script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#myiframe").delay(1000).show(0); });</script>` and this seems to work correctly